# Update two Table on different servers

Tags: sql-server

I have two servers:

- I have table `T1` on database `D1` of `Server1`.
- I have table `T2` on database `D2` of `Server2`.

The two tables have the same fields F1, F2 and F3 (F1 is unique).

When changing T1 table fields, values of T2 table change too, or if there is no record in T2, then Insert.

What is the best way to do this? Please, if possible, provide an example.

Comment: Look up "linked servers".  You can link the servers and have them talk to each other, including doing cross-server queries, and inserts from one server to the other.

Comment: One way to do it is using Linked servers and a for update trigger.

Comment: Is this only for these 2 tables? If more, how about replication?

Comment: you can update t1 and delete and insert from linked server t2.

Answer (score 0):

i used Linked Server:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver     
   @server=N'Server2',   
   @srvproduct=N'',  
   @provider=N'SQLNCLI',   
   @datasrc=N'172.17.17.17';
```

i can update table T2 on database D2 of Server2, from Server1:

```
UPDATE [Server2].[D2].[dbo].[T2]
SET F2 = 'xxxxxx'
WHERE F1 = '123'
```

but when i used in Trigger:

```
USE [D1]
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTTX]
   ON  [dbo].[T1]
   AFTER  UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    EXEC('UPDATE [Server2].[D2].[dbo].[T2] SET F2 = ''xxxxxx'' WHERE F1 = ''123''') 
END
```

ERROR:
The data in row 2 was not committed.
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
Error Message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

how can i fixed it?

Comment: Triggers can slow things down dangerously. I try to avoid them wherever I can. Instead I tend to use a combination of linked servers and transactions. I. e. I first carry out the update/insert operations in the "main" server and then transfer the changed records to the linked server(s). The second operation(s) only starts if the first was successful. And in case the second was unsuccessful I still have a chance to `rollback`all of them.